# Join MVC part to existing ServiceStack project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, servicestack, integration

everyone. I've got ServiceStack project and I want to add mvc part(some controllers and views) to it. 
I tried just installed MVC and add an area, but it doesn't work. 
I tried create new MVC project in the solution, but they work separately.(but I have no ideas how to merge their routes)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check out https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration? It starts out with MVC and adds SS, kind of opposite what you do, but the integration is maybe the same none the less?

Answer (score 1):

To use ServiceStack with **ASP.NET MVC** you need to configure ServiceStack to be hosted on a custom route e.g. `/api` this way ServiceStack doesn't conflict with ASP.NET MVC Razor handling and you can have ServiceStack handle all Service Routes from `/api`.

- [Configure ASP.NET MVC with ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration)
- [Access ServiceStack from MVC](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-Integration)

Otherwise you can just use [ServiceStack's Razor Support](http://razor.servicestack.net), in which case it can't be used with ASP.NET MVC (as it conflicts and tries to hijack Razor views), so to use ServiceStack Razor start with an empty ASP.NET Project and add the NuGet package:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Razor
```

and register the **RazorFormat** plugin, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
```

You can find info about **ServiceStack.Razor** on [razor.servicestack.net](http://razor.servicestack.net/)

Comment: hmm, it's not what I needed. but I can just try to use services from servicestack project in mvc project. anyway thanks